# activerecord find all NOT included in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of team names from another part of code and I want to find all the Teams not in that array. I've tried the following and it doesn't work.

```
@team_exclude_list = ['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3']
@teams = Team.where("name != ?", @team_exclude_list)
```

This is in Rails 3 and the Googles aren't giving me much love.

Comment: Upping this answer because of delicious use of the phrase "the Googles..."

Comment: Up vote as I needed the same thing and also liked the "the Googles"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I've never done this with a string field, but perhaps this will work:

```
@teams = Team.where("name NOT IN (?)", @team_exclude_list)
```

Comment: If you don't have an index on your string column it may be very slow, but it will work as you expect.

Comment: PRECAUTION: If the array is empty, then the query will be like this:
`select * from teams where name NOT IN (NULL)`

Comment: To elaborate on  M.ElSaka  comment, always stuff the array with a DUMMY value so you never use an empty array

Answer (score 68):

Rails 4 solution:

```
@team_exclude_list = ['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3']
@teams = Team.where.not(name: @team_exclude_list)
```

Also, to speed up the query, you can:

- create an index on name

OR

- change the query to use IDs which are indexed by default